# Text box with data validation

Tags: java, loops, javafx, textfield, bufferedreader

I want to ask the user for their gender. I want to create a text box that they can answer the question in.  The do-while loop is to ensure they answer with either "boy" or "girl". There are no errors but it won't run.

Note I have all the necessary imports...

```
public class Culminating_JavaFX extends Application {

    String gender; 

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        TextField textField = new TextField ();

        do
        {
            textField.setPromptText("Are you a boy or a girl?");
            textField.setText("");
            gender = br.readLine().toLowerCase();
        } 
        while (!(gender.equals("boy")) && !(gender.equals("girl")));

        GridPane.setConstraints(textField, 0, 1);
        grid.getChildren().add(textField);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please summarize your problem in the title, not your CV.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Culminating_JavaFX extends Application {

private GridPane grid = new GridPane();
private TextField textField = new TextField();
private Label label = new Label("Are you boy or girl?");
private Button btn;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Answer");

    // set action listener -> runs when button is pressed
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            // process the form
            process();
        }
    });

    // set constraints
    GridPane.setConstraints(textField, 0, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(label, 0, 1);
    GridPane.setConstraints(btn, 0, 2);

    // add components to grid
    grid.getChildren().add(textField);
    grid.getChildren().add(label);
    grid.getChildren().add(btn);

    // show scene
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(grid, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void process() {
    // get text
    String text = textField.getText();

    // process text
    if (text.equals("boy")) {
        label.setText("You are a boy.");
    } else if (text.equals("girl")) {
        label.setText("You are a girl.");
    }
}}
```

[image of required imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peHNn.png)

I wrote a short example, please check it above. Your program goes into do-while loop and stays there. It never gets to the point where it would draw the window and components. That's why it doesn't run.

Comment: Thank you so much you are literally a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, make sure from now on you try to keep your logic code and your graphical user interface code as separate as possible. Never try to cram everything into the GUI class.

Next thing is that the general idea of GUI's is that their logic can't be tied up in loops before being ran. When your program runs and calls `start()`, it will proceed downwards and execute code and needs to hit a line called `window.show();`. This displays the window to the user. If your program is stuck in that loop above, it won't ever be able to even display the GUI to the user and thus won't work.

Instead, rethink how your program will work. Since the user needs to select boy or girl, why not use a [ChoiceBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html) for that, or better yet, a [RadioButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/RadioButton.html). Have the user select the choice they want, then perhaps have a `Button` for them to click to submit or have the `ChoiceBox` or `RadioButton` listen for changes by calling:

```
yourRadioButton.setOnAction(e ->
{
    /*
     * Set the Boy Girl value here by calling
     * yourRadioButton.getValue()
     */
}
```

Comment: This was so informative and helpful thank you so much!